# Springboot - Reading From a File in application.yml

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have seen below syntax in a few configs but I cannot find reference or documentation for this anywhere.

```
spring:
    datasource:
        username: FILE(/etc/usernames....)
```

How does this work? Why not use `file:` instead of `FILE(`. Also, any reference would be great.

Comment: Please, provide a complete example where you have seen `FILE()` syntax. In a regular way, it should be `file:` or `classpath:`, but a datasource driver could have implemented a custom reader in another way (I don't know, just I am supposing it).

Comment: You are right. It was indeed a custom reader that was implemented.